# AJAX url not found because the web server is hosted as an sub app of another website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

I need to send an AJAX request, and the program is ok when I run it at my pc.

`$.post("/coupon/sync"/, .....)`

Chrome develpment tools shows that the request url is `localhost:8373/coupon/aync`

But when I publish the website into server, which hosts like:

[image]

(**pm** is the website I published)

The correct request url should be `www.xxx.com/pm/coupon/aync`,
but the actual url is `www.xxx.com/coupon/aync` (/pm is missing), so the server returns me a 404 not found error.

Because **PM** is not a permanent web app name, it may changes to **pm2** or something else. So I don't want to have the  **PM** set in every ajax url property. 
Is there a soluthing?

Answer (score 0):

put "~" sign before your path. check below snippet.

```
$.post("~/coupon/sync"/, .....)
```

Or

```
$.post("../coupon/sync"/, .....)
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Not working. use `~/` the url turns to `www.xxx.com/pm/~/coupon/sync`. And use '../' it is still `www.xxx.com/coupon/aync`

Comment: if ~ is not working then ../ is 100% works.. please make sure that you put it on right place. If possible please share your code base here.